# how to achieve TextInputLayout animation on typing first character rather than on gaining focus?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

TextInputLayout shows animation of hint converting into label on gaining focus. I want this animation when the user types first character.

Comment: Good question, something i would be interested as well